# Alternatives to boolean flags in MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, optimization, boolean, database-schema

I'm using various boolean flags in my tables, and from reading a bit about optimizing performance I came across a widespread tip to avoid using boolean flags.

What are the effective alternatives? Some examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post a link to a resource that advices against using boolean fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using various boolean flags in my tables, and from reading a bit about optimizing 
>   performance I came across a widespread tip to avoid using boolean flags.

In `MySQL`, `BOOLEAN` is just an alias for `TINYINT(1)`.

This means that boolean operations are in fact integer operation.

That, among other things, means that in a query like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   boolean_flag = 0
```

an index on `boolean_flag`, if any, may be used, while in this one:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   NOT boolean_flag
```

the index will not be used.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a lot of boolean fieds, you can use [bit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-values.html)

like

instead of four fields "true, false, false, true" store one number "9" (1001 in binary)